# Где взять весь общий sql синтаксис для всех реляционных СУБД

Tags: sql, syntax

Не могу нигде найти весь набор sql команд общий для всех или для самых популярных СУБД, или хотя-бы исчерпывающий список ключевых слов (выражений) поддерживаемый во всех диалектах, есть стандарты (SQL92, SQL03, ...)  но там не все обязательно для реализации и есть некая свобода в синтаксисе, а вот хотелось бы найти общий синтаксис.

Comment: чтобы приложение не зависело от используемой субд пишут орм и адаптеры для различных субд.

Comment: конечно, есть даже готовые орм, но это дополнительная абстракция требующая ресурсов, хотелолось бы оценить насколько это оправданно в моем случае, если есть возможность избежать дополнительных средств зачем к ним прибегать

Comment: Всё, что описано в стандарте как обязательное к реализации - это и есть гарантированно общее. Остальное - от лукавого.

Comment: Относись к адаптации SQL-кода к конкретной СУБД так же, как к переводу интерфейса на другой язык. Если абстрагироваться от сути - разницы никакой.

Comment: Да если бы обязательные части стандарта действительно гарантировали общее поведение, то в оракле не было бы такого удивительного NULL.